# trends.google.com refused to connect

Tags: javascript, google-trends

When I embed the code provided by Google Trends, I get the following error:

**trends.google.com** refused to connect.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/2213_RC01/embed_loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("RELATED_TOPICS", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"/m/04gc2","geo":"US","time":"today 12-m"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {"exploreQuery":"q=%2Fm%2F04gc2&geo=US&date=today 12-m","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"}); </script>
```

Comment: What environment did you use to try the code? Local or in a server?

Comment: In my computer and in a web hosting domain.com/file.html

Comment: Does the one in the hosting work? Because I tried implementing the same embed code in a live environment and it worked

Comment: Yeah. You can see it here: https://abogadosenminutos.com/h.html

Comment: Any help guys? Thank you.

Comment: Need to access it via domain like localhost/index.html